# About string.Intern in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string

What situation that I need to call `string.Intern` or `string.IsInterned` on `String` value ?

I have this method used by grid to group row :

```
    // get grouping value for DataGrid
    string GroupItemAccessor(object value)
    {
        COA coa = (COA)value;
        return string.IsInterned(coa.GroupName);
    }
```

If I don't call `string.Intern` the result is wrong, this grid should group by value of `GroupName`.

[image: String.Intern not used]

This if `string.Intern` used (like example code) it work as I expected.

[image: String.Intern used]

Comment: What happens if you just do `return coa.GroupName;`?

Comment: Can you post how you set the grouping of the grid? And what grid control are you using? Is this webforms, winforms or wpf?

Comment: This was WinForm, I'm using SuperList for the Grid [link](http://superlist.codeplex.com/).

Comment: We need more detail, particularly how you are using the result of `GetItemAccessor`. I suspect it is being passed to something that is doing a reference equality rather than value equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you get a different result is that you are not grouping on the string value, you are grouping on the string reference. The strings are not treated as strings when grouping, but as objects, so only the references are compared, not the content.

When you read the values from the database, each string will be a separate instance, even if they have the same value. The first two strings "AAA" for example will be separate objects, not references to the same object.

If you can't make the grid group on the string values, using `String.Intern` is one way to make the strings the same instances, so that the grouping works anyway.

However, you might want to use your own method of making the strings the same instances, as interning the strings means that they will never be garbage collected. You can use a class like this:

```
public class LocalIntern {

  private Dictionary<string, string> _intern = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  public string Intern(string value) {
    if (_intern.ContainsKey(value)) {
      return _intern[value];
    } else {
      _intern.Add(value, value);
      return value;
    }
  }

}
```

When you populate the grid again, you just create a new `LocalIntern` object, and the strings held in the previous one can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, `SuperList` probably does an identity check for grouping (reference checking) - if that is indeed the case, strings that are not interned would be considered different even if they are the same string.

In such a case, the strings will need to be interned in order for the control to group correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I will check `SuperList` source code to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

If I would guess then I'd say that the grid uses Reference Equality. To my knowledge, only literal strings are interned.

So without interning coa.GroupName, two group names that are equal are not reference equal and thus not the grid seems to treat them differently.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I will check `SuperList` code to confirm this.